# Looking for dynamic Formula Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have been using this below formula to present counting 1 to 11.

I have number of data where i am applying this formula manually which takes a lot time.

I just want that If Col"B:B" has this Word i.e., "SHAUK" again over again then formula should start counting again 1 to 11.

I have added an example sheet please look into this issue.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
=SEQUENCE(11,1)
```

Comment: sure looks like an XY problem i'm afraid? https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 1, ),                            QUERY({""; 
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 2, )}, "limit "&ROWS(B3:B), 0),  QUERY({"";"";  
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 3, )}, "limit "&ROWS(B3:B), 0),  QUERY({"";"";"";
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 4, )}, "limit "&ROWS(B3:B), 0),  QUERY({"";"";"";"";
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 5, )}, "limit "&ROWS(B3:B), 0),  QUERY({"";"";"";"";"";  
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 6, )}, "limit "&ROWS(B3:B), 0),  QUERY({"";"";"";"";"";""; 
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 7, )}, "limit "&ROWS(B3:B), 0),  QUERY({"";"";"";"";"";"";"";
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 8, )}, "limit "&ROWS(B3:B), 0),  QUERY({"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 9, )}, "limit "&ROWS(B3:B), 0),  QUERY({"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 10, )}, "limit "&ROWS(B3:B), 0), QUERY({"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";""; 
 IF(B3:B="shauk", 11, )}, "limit "&ROWS(B3:B), 0) }),, 9^9))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
COUNTIFS(LOOKUP(ROW(B3:B),FILTER(ROW(B3:B),B3:B="SHAUK")),LOOKUP(ROW(B3:B),FILTER(ROW(B3:B),B3:B="SHAUK")),ROW(B3:B),"<="&ROW(B3:B))>11,,
COUNTIFS(LOOKUP(ROW(B3:B),FILTER(ROW(B3:B),B3:B="SHAUK")),LOOKUP(ROW(B3:B),FILTER(ROW(B3:B),B3:B="SHAUK")),ROW(B3:B),"<="&ROW(B3:B))))
```

[image]

Comment: pretty interesting approach as always

Answer (score 0):

shorter solution:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/QUERY(FLATTEN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(1, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", IF(B3:B="shauk", "× "&
 QUERY(ROW(1:11),,9^9), 0)), "×")), " "), 
 IF(1=SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(B3:B<>"shauk", 1, "× 1"),,9^9), "×")), " "), 
 COLUMN(A:AAA), )*1, ))), "where Col1 is not null", ))))
```

[image]